# Redirect function doesn't work well - PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, http-headers

Hi I have the following PHP code:

```
 function redirect()
 {
     header("Location: index.php");
 }
 session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION['userName'] ))
    redirect();


 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {   //more code goes here...
   redirect();
  }
```

The problem is that the function `redirect` works only in the following condition:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: This function is a mess

Comment: @JohnConde Can oyu explain why pleas?

Comment: @NaveTseva - if nothing else, the lack of indenting makes it very hard to read

Comment: start the session as the firs thing on your web page, and it is highly unnecessary to call a whole function just to redirect

Comment: its bad indent but its easy to read the function is plain simple function redirect(){header("Location: index.php");}

Comment: the rest is not in the function

Comment: @NaveTseva now that the code was indented by George you can probably see why it redirect in post.... it will redirect if you set $_SESSION['userName'] = true; for example, the question is... what are you trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
    session_start();
    function redirect()
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){
        redirect();
    }elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){   
     //more code goes here...
     redirect();
    }
```

Comment: Should you add a `die()` after `header('location: index.php');` in case there is more code after calling the `redirect()` function? In my noob days I was wondering why my SQL kept executing after redirecting lol

Answer (score 0):

What happens otherwise?
Is there any error?
Something, that happens there?

We need more Information!

This should help:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it works in that condition becuase you are calling it in that condition...
maybe if you use some tabs you can see why

take a look

```
//your function
function redirect(){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
//here your function end

//this is not part of the function
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'] ))
    redirect();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {   
    //more code goes here...
   redirect();
}
```